# How to get rid of Liquibase includeAll tag with formatted .sql changesets error: Cannot find the declaration of element 'databaseChangeLog'

Tags: mysql, database, liquibase

I am using a Gradle Spring project with liquibase. To run liquibase I am running the jar created by compiling the project. I am trying to use the liquibase "includeAll" tag in an xml changelog to run all formatted sql changelog scripts inside a directory I've called includeAllScriptsTest (currently contains only one .sql file named test.sql with one changeset).

If I try to use includeAll in my master db-changelog file, at run time liquibase returns the error: file:///.../conf/db/db.changelog-master.xml/ is not a recognized file type.

In an attempt to get around this, I reference from my db-changelog-master.xml another xml called includeAll-changelog.xml. In this file I have the includeAll tag, below are the contents of this file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog 
        xmlns="https://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog conf/xsd/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">
    <includeAll path="***/includeAllScriptsTest/" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Inside the folder includeAllScriptsTest is a single file called test.sql, with the contents as below:

```
--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset author:1  dbms:MySQL splitStatements:true endDelimiter://

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `TESTINCLUDEALL`;//

CREATE PROCEDURE `TESTINCLUDEALL`()

BEGIN

SELECT * FROM TABLE;
END;//
```

However, this gives me a different error at run time: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'databaseChangeLog'. I've found online conflicting information regarding whether it is possible to use includeAll with the version of liquibase used by my project. I'm currently using 3.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element
> 'databaseChangeLog'

This error is an XML Parsing error, pointing `databaseChangeLog` is not declared in the xml schema.

May be you can try using following XSD in your changelog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">
    <includeAll path="***/includeAllScriptsTest/" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

If this still doesn't help, please have a look at few points in answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63741980/liquibase-cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-databasechangelog-in-xml-ch).

Comment: Thanks. I needed dbchangelog-4.0.xsd, in addition to changing my liquibasecore version to be the latest version (4.3.5). After that I had some checksum errors which I resolved by adding "runAlways:true" after my endDelimter statement. After those changes I got this to work with no issue.